# Primary custom color not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text, flutter-theme, themedata

I have a problem here I want to change color of textbutton from themedata but its not working. Here is my code :

```
darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor:Colors.white,
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.white),
        )
      ),
```

and my button code :

```
 TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
             primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
            onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Hellosir",))
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? What color is it right now and what color do you want it to be?

Comment: Yes sir I have screenshot. The  color is right now dark and I want my textbuttons text White  in darktheme.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two problems why this is not working.

- First, you want to access `ThemeData` defined in `darkTheme`, but your `themeMode` is not dark. So in `MaterialApp` add `themeMode: ThemeMode.dark` parameter as well.
- Second, your button where you call `Theme.of(context).primaryColor` is inside same widget as your definition of Theme, and your `context` still doesn't have that data. So only context of children of current widget have this data. Solution would be to make a new widget with your button inside it, or wrap your button with `Builder` widget which have context inside its builder.

Your problem can be first, second or both.

Comment: Sir my i defined my ThemeData in darkTheme and my themeMode is dark in MaterailApp but still not working. Darktheme is working but i want textbutton text color white in darkmode and black in lightTheme. Thank you sir if you get my point

Comment: Did you try to wrap your button with `Builder` widget. Can you also share your code so we can be of more help.

Comment: Sorry sir You were right i wasn't set themeMode as dark. It worked now thanks.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please select the answer as correct. Cheers